# Session from browser, readable in external application

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, browser

Is it possible to read out the session variable from your browser in some external program?

What i mean is the following.

I write a application ( c# , WPF/Winforms ). And read out the session from my browser, i have the name of the session variable. So i can call the specific session variable itself.

Is this possible? I don't find very much on the internet about this topic.

Comment: You'd probably need some major hackery to make this work, and quite frankly you're probably exposing the user to a security hole. Why do you need this functionality? Maybe consider a different approach.

Comment: To answer on both of comments/answers. I wonna use it for development reasons.
Now i always need to debug the application to see what is in my session.

When i could read it out in another application.

Comment: In that case, you could use a database as your state provider and then just look in the database. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478952.aspx

Comment: Did you already used this implementation? You can get all the info ( recursive ) stored in the database.

Comment: It's serialized data. It won't be gorgeous. But it's a start.

Comment: I will try it. But i can't set your comment as right answer. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only information that you can get from the browser is the session id that is stored in a cookie.

You don't even need an external program for that, in Firefox for example: `Tools > Options > Privacy > remove individual cookies`, there you can view all cookies stored in the browser and their values.

The `Session` object and its variables is not available from the browser, it never leaves the server. The only way to get information out of the `Session` object would be for the web application to read it out and send it to the browser as part of a response.

Comment: +1 - if it were available it would be some sort of security breach.