# How to open a browser with session information from a C# application

Tags: c#, .net, session, browser, session-cookies

I have an application that connects to a web server, requests some pages and process them. While doing the work the application authenticates with the server and some stuff is stored at the cookies that identifies the current session.

I need to open a browser to that site from the application using the same session. Is there a way to do this?

I currently work with the server using WebRequest and WebResponse and putting on all the WebRequests the cookies I received on the WebResponse.

Thanks.

Comment: take a look at here it might helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928328/session-from-browser-readable-in-external-application

Answer (score 1):

Utilize the Web Browser control

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w290k23d.aspx

Processing the HTML content directly will be best with the HTML agility pack:

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: The web browser control will process javascript, etc etc?

Comment: @SoMoS: behind the web browser control works a complete MS Internet Explorer, so I guess it will.

Comment: I've done it and have it working but only on the main window of the webbrowser. When I click a link that opens a new window it does not have the cookies set. Any idea?

Comment: @SoMoS: no idea, but perhaps you should post a new question, showing some relevant parts of your code and some more details what you exactly did. Or you edit your question above accordingly, it will show up like a new question her on SO.